# Unable to type in TextField

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, textfield, swiftui

I am creating a `SignUp` Screen using SwiftUI framework.

I have two textfields, `FirstName` and `LastName`, and one button.

I am grouping them in a `VStack`.

When I am running app, the button is tappable but I am not able to type anything in the textfields.

Here is my code:

```
@State var firstName = ""
@State var lastName = ""
var body: some View {

    NavigationView {

        VStack {

            VStack {

                VStack {

                    Group {
                       TextField($firstName, placeholder: Text("First Name")).padding(10)
                    }.background(Color.white).clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
                        .shadow(radius: 3)

                    Group {
                        TextField($lastName, placeholder: Text("Last Name")).padding(10)
                    }.background(Color.white).clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
                        .shadow(radius: 3)

                    Button(action: {
                    }) {
                        Group {
                            Text("Create User").color(.white).padding(10)
                        }.background(Color.blue).clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
                            .shadow(radius: 5)
                    }
                }.padding(12)
                .background(Color.gray)
                .shadow(radius: 5)

            }.background(Color.gray)

        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Sign Up"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like setting `shadow` after color/opacity effects causes issues in this specific scenario.

To make sure the compositing effects render **before** the shadow, you can add `.compositingGroup()` to your `VStack` - right before `shadow` - and that solves the issue.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/3278537-compositinggroup) says:

> A compositing group makes compositing effects in this view’s ancestor views, like opacity and the blend mode, take effect before this view renders.

**Amended code**:

```swift
VStack {
    // [...]  
}
.padding(12)
.background(Color.gray)
.compositingGroup() // THIS
.shadow(radius: 5)
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Sign Up"))
```

---

The UI can be further simplified in this way - it achieves the same result.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var firstName = ""
    @State var lastName = ""

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack {

                    TextField($firstName, placeholder: Text("First Name"))
                        .padding(10)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .shadow(radius: 3)

                    TextField($lastName, placeholder: Text("Last Name"))
                        .padding(10)
                        .background(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(5)
                        .shadow(radius: 3)

                    Button(action: { }) {
                        Text("Create User")
                            .color(.white)
                            .padding(10)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(5)
                            .shadow(radius: 5)
                    }
            }
            .padding(12)
            .background(Color.gray)
            .compositingGroup()
            .shadow(radius: 5)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Sign Up"))
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I believe this should be the accepted answer because it allows the original poster to still achieve the UI he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Shadow added on VStack creating problem. Please check the code below. I have commented out the shadow.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var firstName = ""
    @State var lastName = ""
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            VStack {

                VStack {

                    VStack {

                        Group {
                            TextField($firstName, placeholder: Text("First Name")).padding(10)
                            }.background(Color.black).clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
                            .shadow(radius: 3)

                        Group {
                            TextField($lastName, placeholder: Text("Last Name")).padding(10)
                            }.background(Color.black).clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
                            .shadow(radius: 3)

                        Button(action: {
                            print("Button Tapped")
                        }) {
                            Group {
                                Text("Create User").color(.white).padding(10)
                                }.background(Color.blue).clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
                                .shadow(radius: 5)
                        }
                        }.padding(12)
                        .background(Color.gray)
//                        .shadow(radius: 5)

                    }.background(Color.gray)

                }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Sign Up"))
        }
    }
}
```